# Magento 2.2 CE : Change in Vendor not update in cloud

Tags: customer, magento2.2, validation, name

I changed `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/templates/widget/name.phtml` "name validation" when i did this change in localhost and ran set:upgrade its working properly.

But not in cloud.Why?

I think its because of `vendor folder which is not  updating in cloud`.I tried to add custom module also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **SHOULD NOT** update/change anything in vendor folder if that is template level change then you should copy that file in your theme folder and make necessary changes and then push to your cloud branch / environment.

in order to make above changes copy : 
`module-customer/view/templates/widget/name.phtml` file and

paste in :

`app/design/frontend/Vendorname/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/name.phtml` and make your changes in that file. And push that file to your branch / repo.

Answer (score 2):

Vendor is updating via composer.json.

You shouldn't make changes directly in vendor, because source is downloading directly from repositories.
You can make changes directly in local env, bout you wont be able to push it into project repo.
I see you made changes in core magento module (really? Its bad bad idea -  never do that!).

You should use rewrites in custom module or change *.phtml in custom design Theme.

Comment: yeah then i changed in custom module like i added name.phtml(validation changed) in vendor/module/view/frontend/templates/widget. and added name.php in vendor/module/Block/Widget.Is this enough or i need to set path in any other file

Comment: Easiest way is to make custom module under app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/. If you dont know how it should looks, just google it. Its pretty simple ;) (of course remember about pushing changes) Otherwise if YOu want to use vendor, you should create custom repositories with module, then attach it into composer.json, and run composer update (but its more complicated)